# changing label automatically in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, label

I am trying to change a label automatically in python, I want it to change every half a second, this is my code for tkinter, the function being called (that is being put into "message") returns a new string every half a second, what am I doing wrong?

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("150x136")

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.root)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.root.bind('<Return>', self.parse)
        self.grid()

        self.instruction = tk.Label(self, text = "QuickReader")
        self.instruction.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4)

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        self.submit = tk.Button(self, text="Submit")
        self.submit.bind('<Button-1>', self.parse)
        self.submit.grid(row = 4, column = 0)

        self.words = tk.Label(self, text = "Start")
        self.words.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 4)


    def parse(self, event):
        filename = self.entry.get()
        message = open_txt(filename)
        self.words.set(message)

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

Application().start()
```

Comment: Where is the code that `change every every half a second`?

Answer (score 1):

To change label text, use one of following:

```
self.words.config(text=message)

self.words.configure(text=message)

self.words['text'] = message
```

Answer (score 1):

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm

> You can associate a Tkinter variable with a label. When the contents of the variable changes, the label is automatically updated:

```
v = StringVar()
Label(master, textvariable=v).pack()

v.set("New Text!")
```

So, that should be pretty easy to implement.